# How can I get a element in Cypress based on a dash MATCH id

Tags: cypress, plotly-dash

I would like to test some dash plotly UI functions with cypress but I have some problems with ids based on dash [Pattern Matching](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks#simple-example-with-match), e.g.:

[image]

Trying to use the id, as found in the DOM, I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried the test with the following sytax:

```js
cy.get('[id="{"index":0,"type":"dynamic-dropdown"}"]').should('exist')
```

```js
cy.get('[id={"index":0,"type":"dynamic-dropdown"}]').should('exist')
```

EDIT:

I've also found this based on the browser developer mode, which will not throw a syntax error but the element can not be found:

```js
cy.get('[id="{&quot;index&quot;:0,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dynamic-dropdown&quot;}"]').should('exist')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the element

```js
cy.get('.dash-dropdown')
  .then($el => console.log('attributes', $el[0].attributes))
```

you see a NameNodeMap with three items

```js
0. id
1. index":0,"type":"dynamic-dropdown"}"
2. class
```

so (at least in chrome) the browser has split the id because of the internal double quotes. The `id` value is `{`, the remainder becomes an attribute key with no value.

You can apply a filter based on this pattern

```js
cy.get('.dash-dropdown')
  .filter((index, el) => {
    const id = el.getAttribute('id')
    return id === '{' && el.hasAttribute('index":0,"type":"dynamic-dropdown"}"')
  })
  .should('have.length', 1)   
  .and('have.text', 'one')      // passes
```

Tested with

```html
<body>
  <div id="{"index":0,"type":"dynamic-dropdown"}" class="dash-dropdown">one</div>
  <div id="index-type-dynamic-dropdown" class="dash-dropdown">two</div>
  <div id="dynamic-dropdown-type-index" class="dash-dropdown">three</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks pretty interesting but unfortunately, it is not working for me. I get an error `Expected to find element: ``, but never found it. Queried from element: <div#{"index":0,"type":"dynamic-dropdown"}.dash-dropdown>`

Answer (score 0):

## Single Selection

By changing the outer quotations marks from "single" to "double" (`cy.get("")`), using "single" quotations marks for the id definition (`[id='']`) and escaping the inner "double" quotations marks (`\"index\"`) cypress can detect the correct element:

```js
cy.get("[id='{\"index\":0,\"type\":\"dynamic-dropdown\"}']").should('exist')
```

## Selector Approach

Another solution is based on cypress [Selector](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Selector) and looks like this:

```js
cy.get('[id*=index][id*=type][id*=dynamic-dropdown]')
```

It will match multiple elements, which include the words "index", "type" and "dynamic-dropdown" but without any order.

So, ids like the following would also match:

```js
<div id="index-type-dynamic-dropdown"></div>
<div id="dynamic-dropdown-type-index"></div>
```